# What is this strange Olympus startup message showing hands pointing at a camera from different directions?

Tags: olympus

Whenever I turn on my Olympus TG-4 I get a strange message which pops up for a few seconds and then disappears.  I am baffled by what this message is trying to tell me and also is a little bit distracting as it obscures the view when I am try to take a picture.  I've trying to looking through the manual and also online, but could not find any reference to this.

Can anyone tell me what this is and/or how to disable it?

[image]

Comment: The hands depict tech support, the manufacturer web site, and the vendor you bought the camera from all pointing to the others as who is supposed to handle your problem.

Comment: If I contacted all those people first, I wouldn't be able to enjoy your sarcastic comment.

Answer (score 4):

Alright, I think I figured it out.  This is specific to Snow mode which allows for gloved operation of the camera.  From  the manual:

1. Tap the right or left side of the camera body once.
   • The picture mode selection screen is displayed.
2. Tap the right or left side of the camera body to select a function.
3. Tap the back of the camera body twice to confirm your selection.

Take a picture: Tap the back of the camera twice (Only for the [Snow]
mode).

Comment: There is a similar interface on Olympus cameras with underwater operation modes.